# Capture paste into HtmlEditorExtender TextBox and modify it

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, htmleditorextender

My goal is to capture the pasted data into a `TextArea` attached to an `HTMLEditorExtendor` and remove all the html, then put that modified data into the control. Is this possible? I've tried to grab the `OnPaste` event but it doesn't seem to fire. This is what I have so far:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var txt = $('#<%=txtText.ClientID%>');
        txt.on('paste', function () {
            var element = this;
            setTimeout(function () {
                alert("PASTE");
                text = $(element).val();
            },100)
        });
    });
</script>
<hr />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtText" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="200px" Width="500px" />
<ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender ID="HtmlEditorExtender1"
    TargetControlID="txtText" DisplaySourceTab="true"
    runat="server">
```

I cannot get the `PASTE` function to fire. Hopefully I am heading in the right direction here.